# How to import object of object from file in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

How can I import object of object from file in typescript. I know I can import like `import house from 'a/b/c/house'`. but can I just import `parent`? so I do not need to write the code like
`house.grandparent.parent.xxx`

```
#filepath: a/b/c/house.ts
const house = {
  grandparent: {
    parent: {
      childa: (text: string) => `s'${text}')`,
      childb: 'b',
      childc: 'c',
    },
  },
};

export default house;
```

Comment: No, but you can write `const { grandparent: { parent } } = house;` in the file that imports from `house.ts` if you don't want to keep using `house.grandparent.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the objects.

```
// house.ts
export const parent = {
  childa: (text: string) => `s'${text}')`,
  childb: "b",
  childc: "c"
};

export const house = {
  grandparent: {
    parent: parent
  }
};
```

```
// some-consumer.ts
import { house, parent } from "./house";

console.log(house);
console.log(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Unfortunately [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) does not work like object destructuring.

but you can do this:

```
const constParent = require('a/b/c/house').grandparent.parent;
```

Hope I can help you